# How to asynchronously callback Lua function in C/Objective-C?

Tags: c, objective-c, asynchronous, lua

I want to wrap http request of Objective-C to Lua, but I don't know how to asynchronously call the function parameter passed in. When I use `lua_State` inside the callback function, it's invalid.
Can anyone help?

```
/*
 Usage in Lua:

 function successHandler(result)
    print('success: '..result)
 end

 function failureHandler(error)
    print('failure: '..error)
 end

 httpRequest(urlString, successHandler, failureHandler)
*/
static int httpRequestProxy(lua_State *L)
{
    size_t l;

    const char * url_ = luaL_checklstring(L, 1, &l);
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:url_];

    [HttpManager request:url success:^(NSString * result) {
        NSLog(@">>>>>>>> lua state top: %d", lua_gettop(L)); // return 0

        NSLog(@">>>>>>>> success: %@", result);

        if (lua_isfunction(L, 2))
        {
            lua_pushstring(L, [result cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            lua_call(L, 1, 0);
        }
    } failure:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@">>>>>>>> failure: %@", error.localizedDescription);

        if (lua_isfunction(L, 3))
        {
            lua_pushstring(L, [error.localizedDescription cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            lua_call(L, 1, 0);
        }
    }];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When the callback is invoked, the Lua stack will be in a completely different state, since other code is run after the function. You have to find some globally-accessible table (preferably the registry or a table inside) and use `luaL_ref` to place the function in the table and obtain a reference to it. You can store the reference (as an integer) then, and once the callback is invoked, fetch the function from the table via the index (and call `luaL_unref`). Just be sure the callback isn't invoked in another thread, since Lua doesn't like that. ;-)